# how to make an array from the values of a column in pandas while dropping the index

Tags: arrays, pandas

I have a data frame about movies. One of the columns is titled 'genres'. I want to take all the string values from the genres column and convert it into an array. I am using the loc function to do this.

genres_list = df.loc[:,'genres']
this list has an index and I can not get rid of it using the .reset_index() function.
[this image is of the indexed list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkksR.png)

Answer (score 1):

so the thing that worked for me is using the `.values` tool.
In an example that looks like that:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2], "B": [3, 4]})
>>> 
>>> list = df.loc[:,'A']
>>> list
0    1
1    2
Name: A, dtype: int64
>>> list = df.loc[:,'A'].values
>>> 
>>> list
array([1, 2])
>>>
```

This still is a numpy array but can be converted with `list.tolist()`

*Reference: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/python+dataframe+to+array+without+index*

Answer (score 1):

Easy:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2], "B": [3, 4]})
>>> df['A'].to_list()
>>> [1, 2]
```